# Ionic: Why the Android keyboard "next" button try to validate a form?

Tags: android, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I created a form sothat a user can signup.
With Android (5.0), when focusing on an input field, the android keyboard pops, and I have a "next" button (right arrow), this is good.

However, when tapping it, it always tries to submit the form instead of focusing to the next field.
Plus, I would like that the last field has the "validate" (tick) button instead of the "next" one.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

try to use the attribute "novalidate" in your form like this:

```
<form novalidate></form>
```